# Concept of pointers in C is not clear

Tags: c, unix

I tried the code on Ubuntu terminal

```
int main() {
    int y = 10;
    int *int_ptr;
    int_ptr = (int *) y;
}
```

I've assigned these code in a program.I want to know about proper implementation of code above by explanation of steps. At last line of code, if it was int_ptr= &y;
I had no problem but with my code I'm not getting what I'm pointing towards with pointer int_ptr.

Comment: do you understand the difference between `y` and `&y` ?

Comment: Read a good book on `C`

Comment: We are not teachers, to do free basic C courses online.

Comment: The last statement does not assign the address of `y` to `int_ptr`; it converts the value stored in `y` (10) to a pointer type and assigns that result to `int_ptr`.

Comment: @dlmeetei: The problem with "read a good book on C" is that most books on C are *awful*.  We need to cite specific books which we know are good (such as [King](http://knking.com/books/c2/index.html) or [Harbison & Steele](http://careferencemanual.com)).

Answer (score 4):

```
int *int_ptr;
```

`int_ptr` is meant to store address of a variable of type `int`.
To get address of variable say `int t` you need to use & operator.
**But by doing what you did above you just assigned integer 10 to `int_ptr`.**

When you declare variable say

```
int x = 34;
```

There are two things at play:

- address where x is stored (e.g. 0x10000); this address is obtained with & operator.
- and 34 which is value of x.

To access `x` via pointers, you need the first value.

Answer (score 0):

With the last line, you assign to int_ptr the address 0x0000000A.
So with *int_ptr, you're reading the piece of memory which address is stored at 0x0000000A.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the code posted, but the cast `(int *)` is masking it.

You should take the address of `y` to make `int_ptr` *point to* `y`:

```
int main(void) {
    int y = 10;
    int *int_ptr;
    int_ptr = &y;
}
```

Using the cast, you are telling the compiler that you know what you are doing and really want to convert the *value* of `y` as the address of some `int` to store into `int_ptr`.  Without the cast, the compiler should issue a warning telling you about the probable programming error.